# LED not turning on with following code

Tags: arduino-uno, led

LED is not turning on with the following code. Have tried multiple LED's and double checked wiring. What's wrong? Using an uno.

```
int ldr = A1;
int  ldrVal = ldr;
int led = 6;
int lvalue = 900;





void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);     

delay(1000);                               

}




void loop() {

Serial.println(analogRead(ldrVal));
if (ldrVal > lvalue) {

digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
}
delay (50);

if (ldrVal < lvalue)
{
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}
delay (1000);

}
```

Comment: Start by using good names for the variables. Use the term "pin" in the name of a variable that is a pin numer. For example ledPin and ldrPin. Do not mix the value of a sensor with the pin number. The level at which the led is turned on can be called "triggerLevel" or "switchLevel" or something else. Do not use two statements in a single line (for example `Serial.print` and `analogRead`). Use the same style for the text everywhere. Use text indents in the same way.

Comment: This is incorrect: int  ldrVal = ldr; and this: Serial.println(analogRead(ldrVal)); There is an example sketch (AnalogInput.ino) that comes with the IDE which would be a great starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the bad indentation and the bad variable naming, which makes your code not only look ugly, but messy and poorly readable, you have multiple problems in your few lines of code.

One problem is the variable `lvalue` never gets set, meaning its value remains `900` no matter what's the value you are reading through `analogRead()`.

A second mistake is your `ldrVal`, which should represent the boundary between *lit* and *powered off*, is set to `A1`, which in turn is a *macro define* for a valid integer, but a very small value (less than `20`).

In other words the code that should decide to turn on/off the LED continously compare 900 and 20 with no opportunity for those values to change: not surprising the LED won't change state, do you agree?

BTW, `50ms` is a very short time interval: if you want to be able to see the LED turn on and then off, increase the delay to 200 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. `analogRead(ldrVal)` does not read the analog pin's value and store it into ldrVal, it is a function who's result is the analog pin value.

Try this edit:

```
void loop() {

int newValue = analogRead(ldrVal);
Serial.println(newValue);
if (newValue > lvalue) {  //Check newValue, not ldrVal
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
}
delay (50);

if (newValue < lvalue)
{
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}
delay (1000);
}
```